# JPA/Hibernate maximum number of joins?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join

Is there a limit to the number of joins permitted in a JPA/Hibernate query?

Since Hibernate [doesn't automatically join](http://www.hibernate.org/118.html#A23), I have to explicitly specify the joins in my JPA/Hibernate query. For example, person has an address, an address has a state. The following query retrieves person(s) with address and state fully loaded:

```
select p, a, s from person p left join p.address a left join a.state s where ...
```

As I keep adding joins, I eventually (after 12-13 left joins) reach a limit where Hibernate generates invalid SQL:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'something69_2_' not found.
```

I do have Hibernate's dialect set to my database implementation, MySQL:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
```

Is there an limit to the number joins Hibernate can handle in a single query?

**Edit 1:** The following is in the log file:

```
could not read column value from result set: something69_2_; Column 'something69_2_' not found.
```

However, `something69_2_` doesn't appear in the SQL query. It's like Hibernate generated a SQL query and is expecting `something69_2_` to be in the results, which is not.

**Edit 2:** Similar problem documented as an [unfixed Hibernate bug HHH-3035](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3035)

**Edit 3:** This is a documented [Hibernate bug HHH-3636](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3636), which has been fixed but is not part of any release yet.

**Edit 4:** I built hibernate-core 3.3.2-SNAPSHOT which includes bug fix HHH-3636 and it did not address this problem.

**Edit 5:** The bug behavior seems to be triggered by multiple `LEFT JOIN FETCH` on ManyToMany or OneToMany relationships. One will work, two or three results in the bug.

**Edit 6:** Here's the stack trace:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:629)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:73)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2214)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2095)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2090)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:388)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:64)
        ... 69 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'something69_2_' not found.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1136)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2777)
        at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.get(IntegerType.java:28)
        at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:1088)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:553)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:689)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
        ... 77 more
```

**Edit 7:** The reason for all these joins is to avoid Hibernate doing n+1 queries, see [Hibernate FAQ on How can I avoid n+1 SQL SELECT queries when running a Hibernate query?](http://www.hibernate.org/118.html#A23)

Comment: Just curious, how complex is the where clause in your JPA query?

Comment: The where clause doesn't matter. I've tried 1) no where clause, and 2) simple where clause (WHERE id=1).

Comment: Why not use subselect fetch rather than join then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is why are you trying to make such a complex query in the first place?

Have you considered different approaches? The documentation on [improving performance](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/reference/en-US/html/performance.html) makes some suggestions.

Comment: Without the joins then Hibernate will make n+1 queries causing very poor performance. See http://www.hibernate.org/118.html#A23

Answer (score 2):

I've once hit the MySQL 5.0 61 table limit with Hibernate:

```
ERROR 1116 (HY000): Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing within the Hibernate code which limits the number of joins.  This could be  a bug in the dialect, or a limitation of the database engine.  But my money's on a bug unrelated to the number of joins!  Have you tried running the SQL directly in an interactive query session?

Comment: The SQL query works just fine. The problem is that Hibernate is trying to read a result field that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to execute with the actual jdbc driver in use? It might be a issue of the jdbc driver.

Although judging from the name of the column, it is looking for, I'd guess there is some trimming/construction of names going wrong. Definitely looks more like a bug than a intended limit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aliasing *all* of your inner joins?  And using those aliases?  I have seen some really strange behavior with Hibernate when you try and use implicit aliasing in the `SELECT` clause to do stuff like this (extremely simplified example):

```
select p.address.state from person p
```

But if you explicitly declare all your aliases it works just fine.  Like this:

```
select s from person p join p.address a join a.state s
```

... or even this:

```
select s from person p join p.address.state s
```