# Does Hibernate EntityManager include Core?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate's implementation of JPA. My Maven `pom.xml` references `hibernate-entitymanager`. My question is, does Hibernate EntityManager (called "Standard Java Persistence API for Java SE and Java EE" on Hibernate's home page) depend on or use the Hibernate Core code?

I've [discovered a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467282/jpa-hibernate-maximum-number-of-joins) with Hibernate that is [documented and fixed](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3636) in Hibernate Core. I want to know if EntityManager uses Core and thus has this fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not include, but depends on Hibernate Core. Have a look at the [detail page](http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.4.0.GA) from MVN Repository to see the list of Hibernate EntityManager's dependencies.

Note that you can use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to show detailed analysis of the dependencies resolved for your POM.

Comment: Starting from Hibernate version 4.0.0.FINAL it does include the Hibernate Core