# Hibernate multiple queries for each object retrieved

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

hibernate excecutes a select statement for each field of the objects being retrieved. This results in 30 seconds to complete a query or a login action on aws RDS instance and 1.32 seconds on localhost.

All of my fields are lazily fetched and when I need one or more of the fields I fetch the object requested with the fields initialized with Hibernate.initialize().

Example.java

```
public Badge getWithBadge(int id, String field) {

    Session session = session();
    try {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Badge> crit = builder.createQuery(Badge.class);
        Root<Badge> root = crit.from(Badge.class);
        crit.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("id"), id));
        Query<Badge> q = session.createQuery(crit);

        Badge result = q.getSingleResult();

        if (field.equals("users")) {
            Hibernate.initialize(result.getUsers());
        } else if (field.equals("equipedBy")) {
            Hibernate.initialize(result.getEquipedBy());
        }

        session.close();
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        retrievalFailed(session, e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'd like to decrease the number of queries being excecuted preferably without using hql prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `join fetch` to avoid [N+1 performance problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155718/hibernate-performance). `join fetch` in JPQL will result in generating SQL join in underlying native statement.

Criteria API method for join fetch:

```
root.fetch("users", JoinType.LEFT);
```