# Lazy loading datatable shows duplicate results with FetchType.EAGER

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces, lazy-loading, criteria

I know there's a lot of questions about this but none of the solutions helped me.

I'm using PrimeFaces to build a lazy loadind datatable. That means that this datatable list is a LazyDataModel list, and I had to develop a LazyDataModel implementation where I overrode the load method.  All of this can be learned from [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf), and it works fine for most of cases, when the datable uses just one table from the database (which is not my case).

Now, I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UNIVERSITY")
public class University {

    @Id 
    @Column(name="ID_UNIVERSITY")   
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO ,generator="SQ_UNIVERSITY")  
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SQ_UNIVERSITY", sequenceName="SQ_UNIVERSITY")
    private Long idUniversity;

    @Column(name="NAME")    
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_DIRECTOR")
    private Director director;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "university")
    private Set<Students> students = new HashSet<Students>(0);

    ...

    public int getStudentsQty(){
        return this.students.size();
    }

    ...
```

Where I'll use the `getStudentsQty()` method to fill one column from my datatable. And here's the Students entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENTS")
public class Students 
{

    @Id 
    @Column(name="ID_STUDENTS") 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO ,generator="SQ_STUDENTS")    
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SQ_STUDENTS", sequenceName="SQ_STUDENTS")
    private Long idStudent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_UNIVERSITY")
    private University student;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    ...
```

Here is the search method that my load implementation will use:

```
public List<University> find(int startingAt, int maxPerPage,
        final String sortField, final SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {

    session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Criteria criteria =session.createCriteria(University.class);    

    List<String> aliases = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(maxPerPage > 0){
        criteria.setMaxResults(maxPerPage);
    }

    criteria.setFirstResult(startingAt);

    addFiltersToCriteria(filters, criteria, aliases);

    Order order = Order.desc("name");

    if(sortField != null && !sortField.isEmpty()){

        if(sortField.contains(".")){
            String first = (sortField.split("\\."))[0];
            if(!aliases.contains(first)){
                criteria.createAlias(first, first);
                aliases.add(first);
            }
        }

        if(sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)){
            order = Order.asc(sortField);
        }
        else if(sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.DESCENDING)){
            order = Order.desc(sortField);
        }
    }
    criteria.addOrder(order);

    return (List<University>) criteria.list();
}
```

And now, my problem. If I use `FetchType.LAZY`, everything works fine, but the performance is terrible, so I wish to use `EAGER`. If I use `EAGER` the results will come duplicated as expected and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995080/hibernate-criteria-returns-children-multiple-times-with-fetchtype-eager). I tried to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in the `University` entity to use a `LinkedHashSet` as suggested in the last link but it didn't worked I don't know how. I also tried to use `DISTINCT` with `Criteria` but it doesn't work because of the `addOrder` that I use, where it asks for joins.

So, I found [this other suggestion](http://floledermann.blogspot.com.br/2007/10/solving-hibernate-criterias-distinct.html) which worked perfectly. Basically the solution is to do a second `Criteria` query, searching only for Universities with ID included in the original search. Like this:

```
private List<University> removeDuplicates(Order order,
        List<University> universities) {

    Criteria criteria;
    List<University> distinct = null;

    if(universities.size() > 0){

        Set<Long> idlist = new HashSet<Long>();

        for(University univ: universities){
            idlist.add(univ.getIdUniversity());
        }

        criteria = session.createCriteria(University.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.in("id", idlist)) ;

        distinct = (List<University>) criteria.list();

        return distinct;
    }
    else{
        return universities;
    }
}
```

So it will bring, say, the first 100 lines for my lazy loadind pagination datatable. In the first `Criteria` search they will be sorted for the first page, and the same 100 correct rows will be present after my second `Criteria` search, but now they will be **unsorted**. It's the correct rows for the first page, but unsorted inside the first page. I cant use "addOder" in the second `Criteria` or else they will come duplicated.

And the strangest thing: if I try to sort the results with `Collections.sort` the results will be duplicated!!! How?? How can I order my result after all?

Thanks!!

**EDIT**: the students count is just an example, I'll need in another scenarios get information inside each associated entity.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are outputting a table listing universities and you want to show the number of students for each university. If so, loading x000 student records into memory just to get a count is crazy (regardless of whether you do it eagerly or lazily).

Try one of the following:

**One**

rather than loading the associated students to get the count use Hibernates @Formula functionality and add a derived property to you University entity.

```
@Formula(value = "select count(*) from students where university_id = ?")
private int studentCount;
```

**Two**

Create a a database view say university_summary_data which includes this count and create an Entity mapped to this view (works just like a table) then in University:

```
@OneToOne
private UniversitySummaryData data;
```

**Three**

Look into Hibernate's @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA) which will allow you to call size() on the mapped collection without loading all Students.

All **much** simpler solutions that what you have.

Comment: Thanks Alan, those tips help me a lot, and I'll use them. But unfortunately this was just an example, I have other cases where I'll need to get associated entities eagerly. If nobody comes up with a solution, I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: See slightly updated answer. Loading x000 students into memory just to get a count is a very bad idea regardless of the fetch mechanism. For the use case at hand then avoiding load altogether is the correct solution either by one of the methods I have suggested or some other mechanism.

Comment: Thank you, and I understand that. But as I said, the students count was just an example. I'll need in another scenario to get a list of entities, that each one has a list of entities, that each one has a list of entities. And it is not for counting purpose, I'll need all the information within them. What am I supposed to do? Or using criteria isn't a good idea in this case?

Comment: Please, how am I supposed to fill the ? parameter in the @Formula?

Comment: Hibernate will do it for you.

Comment: Alan, I'm getting `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2`. And I tried to put "1" instead of "?" to see what would happen and I got this: `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select count(*) from STUDENTS S where S.ID_UNIVERSITY = 1 as formula0_3_, o' at line 1`

Comment: Can you add the formula mapping you have created?

Comment: `@Formula(value = "select count(*) from students S where S.university_id = ?")`

Comment: Sorry. Yeah, you don't use the placeholder. Try @Formula(value = "select count(*) from students S where S.university_id = idUniversity").

Comment: Same thing, `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select count(*) from students S where S.university_id = this_.idUniversity as f'`

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to switch to EAGER loading because the performance with Lazy loading is terrible, but with EAGER loading your performance will be the same. You will still get the select n + 1 problem explained for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651664/can-hibernate-be-used-in-performance-sensitive-applications) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378656/avoiding-n1-eager-fetching-of-child-collection-element-association) with solution.

For performance to improve you need to modify the query that Hibernate will generate. Usually I do a left outer join in Hibernate to obtain this, e.g.

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(University.class)
.createAlias("students", "students_alias", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
.list();
```

And it's best to keep the Hibernate default of lazy loading.