# One select SQL with left join with followed by mapping in code or multiple selects

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a question, most likely a stupid one, regarding selecting queries in hibernate. I have Entity A with a oneToMany relationship to another entity B (A.id_key = B.id_status).

A schema:

```
create table A
(
    id_key  integer      not null
        primary key,
    name    varchar(255) not null,
);
```

B schema:

```
create table B
(
    id_status      integer      not null,
    id_reason      integer      not null,
    primary key (id_status, id_reason)
);
```

I need to get all A entities with some criterias with all B entites inside with some criterias too.

I have 3 ideas:

1. 2 selects. I get all A's that suit my conditions. Then, I create new select with ids of A:

   ```
    createQuery("SELECT b.idStatus as idStatus,"+
                    "b.idReason as idReason, "+
                    "FROM B b"+
                    "where b.idStatus in :ids")
            .setParameter("ids",ids)
   ```

Then I group B entites and map with A:

```
 Map<Integer, List<B>> bMap= bList.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(B::getIdStatus));
 for (A a : aList) {
        List<B> bList = bMap.get(a.getNumStatus);
        a.setBList(bList);
 }
```

2. 1 select with left join and then groupby a.id_key

   SELECT a.id_key, b.id_reason,
   FROM A as a
   LEFT JOIN B as b
   ON id_key = id_status
   #WHERE some conditions

And then the same as for 1'st approach, grouping and mapping.

3. Use hibernate @OneToMany annotation with Eager Fetch and just:

   SELECT a FROM A a where sth.

I don't like the 3rd one, because it creates additional select for Bs for each A entity in list. But maybe I just don't know how to force hibernate use SQL IN operator for annotations. It's ok for native query, but in this case seems like it's the same as for the 1st approach, but I just add annotation, that in other cases I don't need.

But 1st and 2nd look a little complicated, also I don't have many entries and maybe this is an overkill.

Are any of my solutions correct and which one is better? I'm sure there is a better solution, but I can't figure it out.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @ewramner comment I understood that I should use the 3rd approach with @BatchSize annotation.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25210949/2612030, with a reasonable batch size you can make 3 work quite well.

Comment: @ewramner that's actually can help me. Thank you!

Comment: @ewramner I checked it, that's what I needed, thank you very much